# Angular initializing form with @Input value becomes undefined on refresh

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am passing a value from my parent component to my child component using the @Input() communication method. This value is used to initialize the form.

Parent Component.html

```
<child [someValue]="this.randomValue"></child>
```

Child Component.ts

```
@Input() someValue: any;

form: FormGroup;

ngOnInit(){
  this.form = this.fb.group(
    value: this.fb.array([someValue])
}
```

- `someValue` becomes **undefined** when page reloads... why?
- Is there a way to make sure it's not undefined?
- I tried to add this initialize the form in `ngOnChanges` which solves this problem however leads to unexpected results... such as it will always set the `FormArray` to this value and won't let additional values be added to the `FormArray`

Answer (score 0):

Use a setter.

Parent Component

```
<child [someValue]="this.randomValue"></child>
```

---

Child Component

```
set @Input() someValue(val: any){
  this.form = this.fb.group(
    value: this.fb.array([someValue])
}

form: FormGroup;

ngOnInit(){
}
```